# testCafe .switchToWindow() method - how to switch to new window using only part of the url hostname (or title)

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I would like to switch to new window using just part of the url hostname.
For example instead

- *switchToWindow(w => w.url.host === 'testcafe.io')*

I would like to use sth like:

- *(w => w.url.host === /.*testcafe/.*) //regex*
- *(w => w.url.host.includes('testcafe'))*

These 2 above don't work. Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RegExp api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). For example:

```js
fixture('My fixture')
  .page('https://testcafe.io/');

test('First test', async t => {
  await t
    .openWindow('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/')
    .switchToParentWindow()
    .switchToWindow((w) => /example/.test(w.url.href))
});
```